# Is Model View Presenter and Dependency Injenction becoming a new Standard for Android Development?

Tags: android, design-patterns, rx-java, mvp, dagger-2

In the last period i am having the chance to develop some apps for personal reason, and taking a look to what today the companies are organizing their work in the Android Ecosystem i encountered many and many times this kind of project configuration:

- MVP (Model-View-Presenter) as Design Pattern for app architecture;
- RxJava for Reactive programming event-based;
- Dagger2 for dependency injection;
- ButterKnife for fields binding with annotations, used in combo with Dagger2 in order to make your life simplier;
- Espresso and Mockito for testing (really nice to use in this kind of environment with this kind of settings)

So, is this becoming a new standard, in your opinion? If so, do you think that is a good idea apply this (relatively) new guidelines and you usually use this kind of project tools/pattern/libraries into your apps or you think there is something better? If you don't like, it, why? What do you think could be a better approach?

(*Obviously each project is different, and for each project is always better engineerize the best solution/architecture possible for the kind of users/team/dev involved. I am trying to understand/discuss this kind of model that seems to become widely used in his concept in many, many companies*)

Thank you for your time, i hope to create an interesting discussion on the argument in order to all improve our skillset/projects.

Enjoy your day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can not say above methods as standard because Android-Sdk does not have any official support from its Libraries and API's. But As far as development environment is considered now a days Developers are using these methods for writing better code base for their apps, better understanding for future development.

As per my knowledge using these libraries is useful only if they have good support from developers as these are open source libraries. For example I am using [AndroidMVC](https://github.com/kejunxia/AndroidMvc/) right now for MVP pattern. As per my knowledge this is very good library as I am using it since last year but As there is  only one developer working on that library, it's very hard to get support for bug fixes(forget about enhancements).

So while selecting any open source library you should always look all the parameters like support, enhancements, bugs etc.

Libraries like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/), [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), [Couchbase lite](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios), [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit), [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) etc are some evergreen libraries of Android.

But again OkHttp, Retrofit and Volley are used for similar purpose i.e. for networking. Now developer have to choose according to pros and cons of each library.

As far as *question - should we use libraries or not?* is considered. I think YES. We should use these kind of libraries which are stable because it saves lot of time and it's not of use rewriting the code if we already have it in form of library.

Comment: Totally agree with you, personally i already adopted this tools/pratices and i love them. The main porpouse of this question is collect impressions and ideas because we can always improve ourselves :)

Comment: @OmarMohamed Happy to discuss anything about android anytime :)